# Missing required arguments: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key - Travis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I'm getting this error when I run travis `ArgumentError: Missing required arguments: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key`. It stops my build. I'm using carrierwave for fileuploads and storing them on S3. It's strange because It's actually storing them in my S3 bucket so I know that my aws keys are correct. P.S. I'm using Figaro.

Here is my code.

AVATAR UPLOADER:

```
 class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :fog

  def extension_whitelist
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end

  process :resize_to_limit => [50, 50]

  def default_url(*args)
    ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("fallback/" + [version_name, "pete.png"].compact.join('_'))
  end
end
```

### Storage.rb

```
 CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
      provider:              'AWS',
      aws_access_key_id:     ENV["aws_access_id"],
      aws_secret_access_key: ENV["aws_access_secret_key"],
      region: 'us-west-2'
  }
  config.storage = :fog
  config.fog_directory  = "lockdown-bucket"
  config.fog_public     = false
end
```

Main issue here is that my travis build is stoping when it runs `rake` and I get the error in the title. Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: have you set the environment variables? they're case sensitive

Comment: Yeah, It's posting the images to my S3 bucket. It's just failing when I run travis.

Comment: You would need to set the env vars on travis too

Comment: Oh how do I do that?

Comment: Its definitely in travis docs.

Comment: A good tip is to use `ENV.fetch("SOME_ENV_VAR")` as it will fail loudly if the ENV var is not set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to install the gem: `gem install travis`

After that:

`travis encrypt aws_access_id=Your_aws_s3_key --add`

`travis encrypt aws_access_secret_key=Your_aws_s3_secret --add`

it will be automatically added to your `.travis.yml file`

it will be something like that:

`language: ruby
rvm:
 - 2.4.0
env:
  global:
 - secure: dwnrYRL4pm0JIU4Qq4mp...
 - secure: e+rtcUZ8mWVMRq6NP540qtu/ZwYpQ5JT...
matrix:
 - DB: postgresql
script:
 - RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake db:migrate --trace
 - bundle exec rake db:test:prepare
 - bundle exec rspec spec
before_script:
 - psql -c 'create database DB_NAME_test' -U postgres
 - cp config/database.travis.yml config/database.yml`

DB_NAME - your database name

`Your_aws_s3_key` && `Your_aws_s3_secret` must be without quates.